# Basic T-SQL COUNT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, data-warehouse

I'm new to T-SQL and this question is T-SQL Count 101.

I'm studying T-SQL with this site http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-101-lesson-4 but I can't figure out Which part of coding says WHERE(column_name) to execute 'COUNT' if it makes sense? In other words, how does this COUNT know what to count? It just says COUNT everything as Reviews from MovieReview table.....

```
SELECT MovieName,
LEFT(REPLICATE('* ',AVG(Stars)),10)
AS 'Stars',
COUNT(*) AS 'Reviews'
FROM MovieReview
GROUP BY MovieName
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
ORDER BY Stars
```

Result:
[image: Result]

The TABLE name is MovieReview that contains the ratings that the five employees have given to movies they’ve watched in their spare time. This table contains four columns: EmployeeID, Genre, MovieName, and Stars. The Stars field specifies the movie’s rating, where 1 star is the worst rating and 5 is the best rating.

I understand below coding because it specified WHERE. Count everything as '...' From Employee table Where salary is less than 3000.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
AS 'Impoverished'
FROM Employee
WHERE Salary < 30000
```

I need to learn creating reports from Data Warehouse. I learned SQL but most of sites use T-SQL when creating reports, I don't know why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count(*)` counts the number of **rows** that match the where clause if a `where` clause is given, per distinct combination of the `group by` columns if a `group by` column is given.
Except for the behavior noted in the previous sentence, `count(*)` ignores the values in those rows.

Comment: Hi Mureinik, thanks for the answer! So when WHERE is not given,  COUNT counts what GROUP BY is specified? Thanks~

Comment: if you don't have a `where` clause, `count(*)` will give the number of rows per distinct value in the `group by` column.

Comment: Thanks Mureinik, now I get it! :)